# Eclipse equivalent command line commands

Tags: java, jar

is there any way to determine the commands run by Eclipse (in console) whenever we do some operations (like jar file creation) which can also be done through command prompt.

Thanks

Comment: IntelliJ shows you the commands it executes in a window at the bottom of the screen.  But I am not sure about Eclipse.

Comment: Check [this](http://exploreeclipse.blogspot.com/2014/01/enable-eclipse-verbose-for-trouble.html) out. This will enable verbose logging in eclipse. Not sure if the commands will be printed though.

Comment: The underlying issue with regards to this question is, that Eclipse does many of the Java-things with internal logic/code. In contrast to IntelliJ, which relies on the basic Java commands, Eclipse installs own Java libraries and commands, making it harder to reproduce the exact behavior.